# Year attribute is nil upon saving to database - not transferring from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My year attribute isn't transferring from the form dropdown menu. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @movie do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Movie Title", input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :year, as: :date,
            start_year: Date.today.year,
            end_year: Date.today.year - 100, 
            discard_day: true, order: [:year], 
            input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
      </div>
```

Controller code:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Please try again!"
      redirect_to new_movie_path
    end
  end

  private

  def find_movie
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end

  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :year, :genre, :poster, :director, :plot, :rating, :list_ids => [])
  end
end
```

It looks and works as expected in the view, but year is nil when I check the database. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your terminal for the incoming parameters?

Comment: Yes, the year attribute is being permitted in the controller and parameters check out.

Comment: Could you add controller code to the question?

Comment: Controller code added.

Comment: can you show us what the parameters look like as they are passed in, and also any validations on the model.